# openSUSE Tumbleweed: facial recognition for login: howdy and PAM configuration issues

Tags: login, opensuse, pam, authentication

My laptop is an Acer Swift 3. It has a fingerprint sensor, but there’s no Linux driver for this one (last time I checked).

So since I like Windows Hello, I decided to set up face recognition. I’m running openSUSE Tumbleweed (up to date). I found out that the way to go about this was to use `howdy`.

But after (a very painful because of python dependencies issues) installing howdy and adding the 3 files mentioned [here](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Facial_authentication) in the PAM section (btw I basically followed exactly the instructions from this page to setup my system), I found out that:

- `sudo howdy --user myusername add` works (I can save a few faces)
- `sudo howdy test` returns errors, as follows:

```
[ WARN:0@0.374] OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Embedded video playback halted; module source reported: Could not read from resource.
[ WARN:0@0.374] OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to start pipeline
[ WARN:0@0.374] OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created

Opening a window with a test feed

Press ctrl+C in this terminal to quit
Click on the image to enable or disable slow mode

qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.
```

(I did try reinstalling `xcb` but it didn't help)

- after editing howdy.conf so as to allow to run the command without sudo privileges, `howdy test` works, I can see my face being detected live on the screen.
- as long as I complete the steps from the tutorial linked above, when I log out howdy doesn’t activate but more importantly **I can’t log in anymore, passwords no longer work!!!** And if I change TTY even *usernames* are not valid anymore (not even root!). So my only option was to rollback to a system snapshot generated before I edited PAM config.

About PAM config: I didn’t have the files `sddm` `login` and `kde` in my `pam.d` directories, so I created empty ones and wrote

```
auth     sufficient     pam_python.so /usr/lib64/security/howdy/pam.py
```

into them.
I guess that’s where the problem is, this in my opinion can’t be the right way to configure PAM.

So to sum up, two major problems: 1) how do I configure PAM to have howdy start and work at login? and 2) how can I make `sudo howdy test` work?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

---

**EDIT**: I managed to advance a little, on the PAM side (not creating the 3 files and editing `common-auth` with the howdy option in first position) I think my config is now right. But I don't know how to activate howdy...? Online it's written everywhere that it should work out of the box...